# what is the usage of /usr/lib/perf/libperfstat_updt_dictionary in AIX and the relation with command topas?

Tags: aix

Currently I have encountered the same problem as below link:

http://www.aixmind.com/?tag=usrlibperflibperfstat_updt_dictionary

I have solved the same problem, but I want to know the reason.

What is the usage of `/usr/lib/perf/libperfstat_updt_dictionary`?

And why when I set the setuid bit to this file, I can run `topas` in non-root user?
What is the relation between the file and `topas`?

Thanks all.

Updated:
1. Actually, I want to know the usage of `/usr/lib/perf/libperfstat_updt_dictionary`
2. And the relation between command topas and this file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`/usr/lib/perf/libperfstat_updt_dictionary` is an executable. If the setuid bit is set, then it gains the privileges of the owner of the file (which is root in this case).  See [setuid](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Setuid) for more information.  With the effective user of root, it can do anything it wants to.  This opens holes that can be exploited which are explained in the "Security" section of the referenced page.

It creates `/usr/lib/perf/libperfstat_dictionary.dat` which appears to me to be stats only for disks and then topas uses that.

As far as "usage"... I would not call it directly.  Its not a "user" type program but more something hidden in the background used by topas and perftools.  argc and argv are not used.  Its a one trick pony.

Comment: So what is the relationship between this executable and command topas?

Comment: Thank you very much. So is there any document saying that topas will read the /usr/lib/perf/libperfstat_dictionary.dat.

Comment: I doubt it.  Why all the interest?  Do I get a check mark and up tick?

Comment: Because I need to give the reason to my boss.
Anyway, thanks for your answer and you get a check mark

Comment: He may need a more detailed explaination T.T